# full authentication is required to access this resource - Rest webservice call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

My application is developed using spring framework.I have created a new rest webservice using spring framework.

```
@Controller
public class MyTestController {
   @Inject
    private MyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/acc/Status/{accNum}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAccStatus(@PathVariable final String accNum, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
        {
        //logic goes here
        return "success";
  }
```

MyService:

```
public interface BusinessCalendarService {

 //methods..
}
```

I want to see the response of the above webservice. I am using postman tool to see the responses.
When i gave the request as
http://localhost:8080/myApplication/rest/acc/Status/322298973, it is showing the below message.

```
HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

The existing controllers works fine, it is with my controller which is showing the above message. Please suggest do i need to do any code modifications? I have followed the same way as other controllers were written.

Comment: You have some Spring Security configuration somewhere that's saying the path requires full authentication. Post any security configuration you have.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to authenticate the user before posting to that uri, or, if it's a uri that should be able to be accessed without being authenticated, add the uri to your `authorizeRequests().antMatcher()` within the http security part of your config.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html